# Facebook OAuth with Devise in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth

After spending 30+ hours trying to get a solution to this and searching all corners of the earth, I am posting my first question here ever.

No matter what I try, I get

> 'The parameter app_id is required'

I've followed the docs to a T from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Here are the pieces I thought were most important...any ideas what I could be missing?

***config/initializers/devise.rb***

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET"], scope: 'user'
```

I've checked that the env params are correct on my system.

***user.rb***

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      # user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      # user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it seems like , `ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"]` returning blank or nil. Just try double check if you are getting a value from `ENV` variable, try to print it before using..

Comment: Yea not sure why, it works perfectly if I do echo $FACEBOOK_APP_ID from console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "xxxxx", "xxxx"
```

Using the actual values inside config/initializers/devise.rb worked for me.

Comment: Wow I have no idea why OAuth can't use ENV variables...that really sucks. I'll have to find another way to store them then, because I plan on pushing this project to Github.

Comment: Alright Figaro works fine. I am still dumbfounded as to why using ENV with export=... isn't working, since I've used it in other projects. Oh well, Figaro is more convenient anyhow. I'm just sad it took me this long to get it all working. This whole time I thought I was skipping a step in the devise setup haha.

Comment: Great, don't wait 30 hours until you ask next time haha. Also don't forget to upvote my answer please. Thanks

Comment: even though @RailsOuter's solution works, preferred way is to use the `ENV` variables. Reason behind is that, 1) you can move the sensitive information out of the code base, 2) Easily manage different envs (Ex: `development`, `production`) by having different `ENV` variables. I personally prefer to use dotenv (https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)